# Why we use starting and ending tag as <? ?> in php?

Tags: php

I am using php and from the beginning i was wondering about the thing that why we use 
`<? ?>` tag as starting and ending of the php tag.

I know its scripting used for differentiating php from other language but i want to know that why we use  and not any other tag as the starting and ending tag?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean <? ?>, <% %> is used for ASP.NET. Also you should use <?php ?> as it is fully supported across server configurations

Comment: This question is a humiliation for php.

Comment: @JLevett, Since PHP 5.4.0, `<?=` is always available.

Comment: I believe you can use both styles of sharthand tags for php best practice is to use <?php ... ?> see [this](http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/php-tutorial/opening-amp-closing-php-tags.aspx)

Comment: sorry it was my mistake..why we use <? ?> and <?php ?> in php

Comment: Unless Rasmus Lerdorf is reading this question, no one can answer you about why he picked `<?php`. I'm voting to close this.

Comment: further to my comment the php.ini file contains `short_open_tag` and also `asp_tags` directives to enable/disable these features

Answer (score 5):

`<%` and `%>` are only supported on some servers. The usual PHP tags are `<?php` and `?>` and these are the ones you should use.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, we don't use <% and %> tags. Theses tags are used by ASP scripts, and there is a special configuration in php.ini to use asp-like tags. PHP use `<?php` and `?>` tags (or `<?` `?>` in shorter form). In pure PHP files the closing tag in not required.

Why using `<%` ? Maybe because `<?` is the beggining of an XML file too, so it can be confusing for parsers, but not for standard web server as PHP files never be sent to browsers.

Comment: I still call BS on the parser thing.  WHY would you send php through an XML parser?  Would you send Java code into a XML parser?  Absurd!

Comment: Because PHP files are near HTML files on the server? Because you can mix XHTML and PHP in the same file, and want to parse XHTML with an XML parser on the server side? Because Java is compiled in bytecode and PHP interpreted?

Comment: That's still absurd.  Make your tools aware of the context.  Separate the file types, include them as necessary, use make, rake, ant, or whatever build tool to run the appropriate tools on the appropriate files.   Your arguments are all laziness.  I also have .jpg files next to my php files, should I run them through an XML parser?

Comment: In fact I often use <? for my files, I just find some ideas about usefullness of not using <? . You don't need to be so agressive. A file mixing PHP and XHTML is a PHP file, and an XHTML file at the same time. And a developer don't always have the choice, it may be legacy code or legacy practice. It's just a liberty you can choose to use.

Comment: In my experience, it is the php fanboys that are aggressive in maintaining this stance, for example, downvotes with no comment in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637007/why-we-use-starting-and-ending-tag-as-in-php/8637097#8637097  ... and, even if your php document that contains xhtml is a valid XML document, that doesn't mean the output will be.

Answer (score 0):

correct tag for php are **<**?php ?**>**.

**<**% %**>** are opening/closing tag for ASP script (vbscript and other microsoft languages).
However, some misconfigured php installations accept those also for php, but try to avoid this usage as you may have some trouble if you want to run your script on an other server.

To be complete, the closing tag ?> is useless if you script contain only php code. It's event recommended to not using it, to avoid problem when you play with cookies ...

Answer (score -2):

This is one of the stupidest things in the php community.  The accepted practice as stated by others is to use `<?php ?>` and to print a variable, `<?php echo $foo ?>`  I suspect this was originally out of spite to not be confused with ASP's `<% %>`

Which is easier to read?  RoR's `<%= foo %>` or `<?php echo $foo; %>`   I think most non-php people would opt for the shorter one.

In addition, there is an argument that `<% %>` breaks XML parsers, whereas `<? ?>` passes through them.  I think that is a silly argument, because a php file is not an XML file... You would parse the XML produced by running through php first, which would no longer have the php markers.  Why would you run php through an xml parser? Would you run a C++ file through an XML parser?

Comment: i am not debating or asking on the short or full tag of php.i just want to know why we use <? ?> or <?php ?> as staring or ending of php?

Comment: My best guess is out of spite to not be confused with ASP.

Comment: Ah the down votes.  The php community has found this post.  I always get yelled down if I bring up this topic.  The upvoted answer does not answer the question, mine at least attempts to answer why.  This is the usual reaction to doubting the php way.